# How to show driving distance on openlayers map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, uwp, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers map in UWP desktop app.But my opelayers Map is not showing driving distance(Route) from one point to another point. i can able to show map and markers on it like location markers on map but not able to show route between source and destination.

Any help Would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 var lat = mylatitutde;
 var long = mylongitutde;
 var zoom = 8;
 var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
 var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");  

 // Transform from WGS 1984
 var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 

 // to Spherical Mercator Projection
 map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map");
 map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
 var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
 map.addLayer(mapnik);

 var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
 map.addLayer(markers);

 var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(long, lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
 var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position);
 var feature = new OpenLayers.`enter code here`Feature(markers, position);
 vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);

 markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));


 map.setCenter(position, zoom);
 map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Is there any solution to show route between two locations in Open Layers map??

Comment: The people spending their free time to help others would appreciate if you as querist would invest a few seconds and format question before submitting

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the optimal path to drive from A to B is not a task OpenLayers is designed for. It is merely there to display a map and map-related-things on it.

Of course, OpenLayers can display a route, but you somehow first have to calculate it. There are good examples on the OL website. Here is [one showing a precalculated route as PolyLine](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html), or one using [IGC data](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/igc.html).